# How to set-up zoom level in iOS?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, cllocation, mkcoordinateregion

I am using the code given below to set a region in map view:

```
    CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = (CLLocationCoordinate2D )[self geoCodeUsingAddress:searchBar.text];

    CLLocationDistance visibleDistance = 100000;
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc, visibleDistance, visibleDistance);
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];

    [self.mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
    [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:loc];
    [self.mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
```

It shows the entire map in a small area. How can increment the zoom level?

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a help of `span` value for MapView. Animate to that small area and span map to zoom for required value.

Use below code:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = (CLLocationCoordinate2D )[self geoCodeUsingAddress:searchBar.text];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center.latitude = loc.latitude;
    region.center.longitude = loc.longitude;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.15f;       // Decrement value to zoom
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.15f;      // Decrement value to zoom

    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

} completion:^(BOOL finished) { }];
```

Comment: But it is not working for me. I've changed the region.span.latitudeDelta and region.span.longitudeDelta. but no luck !

Comment: Does it not zoom? What issue you got? Where you place this code?

Comment: I'm calling this method when the user search for a place. code placed in the searchBarTextDidBeginEditing: method

Answer (score 0):

Change the `visibleDistance` to a smaller number. Experiment until you find something you like.

Comment: By the way, there is no point setting the center coordinate after you have set the region. The region defines completely what the map will show.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved the issue by removing

```
[self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:loc];
```

I worked well when i removed the above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = (CLLocationCoordinate2D )[self geoCodeUsingAddress:searchBar.text];
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc, visibleDistance, visibleDistance);
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.15f;     
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.15f; 
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
[self.mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
```